# Child component correctly deletes parent's state's object entry, but wrong child is unmounted upon re-render

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I have an `Order` component which keeps a Javascript object in `this.state.newItems` and renders `OrderItem` components for each of it's child

`OrderItem` also receives callbacks to operate on the parent's state

I am getting a behavior such as the javascript object being updated correctly on delete, but the wrong node is unmounted

Video:
https://streamable.com/bjesf

As you can see, the wrong `OrderItem` component is unmounted

Relevant code:

```
export default class Order extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)

    this.state = {
        newItems: null
    }

    if (this.props.isNew)
        this.data = null
    else {
        this.data = { ... this.props }
    }
  }

  /* _commit = () => {
    console.log(this.data)
    if (this.data.trim().length > 0)
      socket.emit('article:client:insert', { name: this.data })
  } */

  addNewOrderItem = async () => {
    let _ = this.state.newItems ? { ... this.state.newItems } : {}

    _[Date.now().toString()] = {
        articleData: {
          isNew: true,
          unitaryPrice: 0.0
        }
    }

    await this.setState({
        newItems: _
    })

    console.log(this.state.newItems)
  }

  deleteNewOrderItem = async id => {
      let _ = { ...this.state.newItems }

      console.log("Deleting " + id)
      delete _[id]

      await this.setState({
        newItems: _
      })

      console.log(this.state.newItems)
  }

  updateNewOrderItem = async (id, value) => {
      let _ = { ...this.state.newItems }
      _[id] = value

      await this.setState({
        newItems: _
      })

      console.log(this.state.newItems)
  }

  renderNewItems () {
      if (!this.state.newItems) return null

      let _ = []
      for (let _id in this.state.newItems)
          _.push(
            <OrderItem 
                articleData={this.state.newItems[_id].articleData}
                id={_id}
                onUpdate={this.updateNewOrderItem}
                onDelete={this.deleteNewOrderItem}
            />
          )

      return _
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this

    return (
       // ...
        {
            this.renderNewItems()
        }
       // ...
    )
  }
}


export default class OrderItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    base64img: null
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.setData(props)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log("Will unmount " + this.props.id)
  }

  setData (props) {
    this.data = { ...props }
    delete this.data.onDelete
    delete this.data.onUpdate
  }

  handleImageInsert = (event) => {
    let objectFile = event.target.files[0]
    if (!objectFile) return

    let reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = upload => 
      this.setState({
        base64img: upload.target.result
      })

    reader.readAsDataURL(objectFile)
    this.data.articleData.newImage = objectFile

    this.updateData()
  }

  handleUnitaryPriceChange = e => {
      let newPrice = parseFloat(e.target.value)
      if (newPrice != NaN) {
        this.data.articleData.unitaryPrice = newPrice
        this.updateData()
      }
  }

  handleBriefChange = e => {
    this.data.articleData.brief = e.target.value
    this.updateData()
  }

  handleTableChange = update => {
    this.data = { ... this.data, ... update }
    this.updateData()
  }

  updateData = () => {
    this.props.onUpdate(this.props.id, this.data)
  }

  confirmDelete = () => {
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)
  }

  render () {
    const { data: { articleData } } = this

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          ref={ref => this.fileUploadRef = ref}
          onChange={this.handleImageInsert}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
        />
        <div className="orderTableImageColumn">
          {
            this.state.base64img &&
            <img src={this.state.base64img} style={{width: '100%'}} />
          }
          <div className="orderTableImageColumnControls">
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              className="print-hide"
              color="primary"
              style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
              onClick={() => this.fileUploadRef.click()}
            >
              <PhotoCamera />
            </Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              className="print-hide"
              color="primary"
              style={{ display: 'inline-block', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
              onClick={this.confirmDelete}
            >
              <Delete />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            whiteSpace: 'normal',
            wordWrap: 'break-word',
            width: '65%',
            padding: '2%',
            paddingLeft: '1%',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            display: 'inline-block'
          }}>
            <div style={{display: 'inline-block', width: '50%'}}>
              {
                !(articleData.isPending || articleData.isNew) && <span className='tableLabelSmall'>SKU</span>
              }

              <br /><br />
              <textarea 
                name="brief"
                className='articleBriefTextarea'
                onChange={this.handleBriefChange}
                value={articleData.brief ? articleData.brief : 'Descrizione'}
                />
            </div>
            <div style={{
              display: 'inline-block', 
              width: '47%',
              marginLeft: '1%',
              padding: '1%',
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              backgroundColor: 'gold'
            }}>
              <span className='tableLabelSmall'>PREZZO UNITARIO €</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input 
                type="text" 
                style={{padding: '5px', marginBottom: '3px'}} 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" 
                name="unitaryPrice"
                placeholder='0'
                onChange={this.handleUnitaryPriceChange}
              />
              <br />
              <textarea
                name="needs"
                className='articleBriefTextarea'
                value={articleData.needs ? articleData.needs : 'Materiali, accessori, necessità'}
              />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `data` stored in state?

Comment: `data` is a deep copy of the `OrderItem`'s props, so that is mutable inside that component and I can pass it back to the parent's through injected callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `key` prop on `<OrderItem />` so React knows which props correspond to which component instance:

```
renderNewItems () {
      if (!this.state.newItems) return null

      let _ = []
      for (let _id in this.state.newItems)
          _.push(
            <OrderItem 
                key={_id}
                articleData={this.state.newItems[_id].articleData}
                id={_id}
                onUpdate={this.updateNewOrderItem}
                onDelete={this.deleteNewOrderItem}
            />
          )

      return _
  }
```

The errors in the console are actually warning you about this too.

As an aside, it will be much easier to reason about your code if the child component isn't allowed to mutate the state of the parent.